# Nested Checkbox : Checked / Unchecked children with parent check

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, checkbox, nested

Hi I've got a form with nested Checkbox on three level

With Jquery I need to checked/uncheked all the children when I check a parent level... and of course uncheck the parent if at least one of the children is uncheck

I try but never success that's why I'm calling your help :)

Many thanks to all

My html code :

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/SENV8/86/

```
<fieldset class="floral">
<input type="checkbox" class="familybox cbox">
<label>Level 1</label>
<ul class="valuelist">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cbox mainoption">
        <label>Level 2</label>
        <ul class="suboption">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="cbox">
                <label>Level 3</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="suboption">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="cbox">
                <label>Level 3</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cbox mainoption">
        <label>Level 2</label>
        <ul class="suboption">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="cbox">
                <label>Level 3</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="suboption">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="cbox">
                <label>Level 3</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
```

EDIT : 
I'm here with my script:

```
$('.familybox').change(function() {
        var getparent = $(this).closest('fieldset').attr('class');

        if($('.'+getparent+' .familybox').is(':checked')){
            $('.'+getparent+' .valuelist input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
        } else if($('.'+getparent+' .familybox').not(':checked')) {
            $('.'+getparent+' .valuelist input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
        } 

});
```

Comment: no javascript attempts?

Comment: My tries was such unsuccess i didn't keep them :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See I have Implemented your requirement.

It is needed to make some changes in HTML which I have did in JSfiddle.

Total Jquery script is as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.extend($.expr[':'], {
                unchecked: function (obj) {
                    return ((obj.type == 'checkbox' || obj.type == 'radio') && !$(obj).is(':checked'));
                }
            });

            $(".floral input:checkbox").live('change', function () {
                $(this).next('ul').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));

                for (var i = $('.floral').find('ul').length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    $('.floral').find('ul:eq(' + i + ')').prev('input:checkbox').prop('checked', function () {
                        return $(this).next('ul').find('input:unchecked').length === 0 ? true : false;
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

To see live demo:

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BhaveshKachhadiya/SENV8/100/)</kbd>

Comment: @VaX I have implemented this with demo in JSFiddle please try it and let me know.